# Rails 3.1 assets and layout troubles

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have a rails 3.1 application that uses a default layout with css in "/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css" as per standard practice. This works great with the asset pipelining stuff for the main part of my application.

But I use a different "reporting" layout when I generate a report that uses a /app/views/layouts/showreports.html.erb layout as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "showreports" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "showreports" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mainarea" class="container">
    <div class="span-24 last">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm using `rake assets:clean; rake assets:precompile` to pre-compile my assets and check things are looking good in the manifest file (/public/assets/manifest.yml) and I don't see any references to showreports.css or showreports.js.

When I test my program in dev-mode, unsurprisingly, it can't locate those files.

I'm guessing this is a basic sprockets question with rails 3.1 but I thought sprockets would be smart enough to parse all the layout files for assets (beyond the default application.html.erb file).

Just wondering if this may be a bug or just my misunderstanding on how this should work.

Cheers,

Greg

---

**UPDATE**

After more tinkering, I'm answering my own question as this made the most sense for me...

[This answer really gave the right clue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167805/using-rails-3-1-where-do-you-put-your-page-specific-javascript-code/6396728#6396728)

What I was doing wrong was using files named "showreports.css" and "showreports.js" as manifest files.

My fix was to create `/app/assets/stylesheets/showreports` and `/app/assets/javascripts/showreports`  and then to rename my showreports.(css|js) to application.(css|js) inside their respective directories.

After doing so, `rake assets:precompile` found them nicely and added them correctly to the manifest file.

Answer (score 4):

According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html you should also add following:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(showreports.css showreports.js)
```

to your application.rb file

Answer (score 0):

It's a misunderstanding. Rails Assets Pipeline only compiles files located in `RAILS_ROOT/app/assets` and you must reference them directly. If you want another file to be generated simply create another manifest file with similar content to application.css/js. Also check `require` directives to avoid including one file into the other.

Comment: @Pablo_Castellazzi. Thanks, but I'm a little lost on where/how to do this. Would I modify something in config/application.rb to force another manifest file to be generated or would I manually create this?

Comment: A little bit of both. You need to create the files and add them to the array `config.assets.precompile` in `config/environments/production.rb`.