# Page Specific Javascript Not Working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am building a rails app and in order to have page specific app.

I have added this to the bottom of my `index.html.erb` for my `PagesController`:

```
<script> </script>
```

The code sets the `navbar` opacity to `0` if it is at the top, but somehow this also shows up in the `new.html.erb` for my `contactcontroller`.

Any idea on how this is happening?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function() { /* run on load */

        if ($('.nav-fixed-top').css("opacity") == 0) {
            $('.nav-fixed-top').fadeTo(500, 1); /* fadeIn if not visible */
        } else {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
                $(".nav-fixed-top").fadeTo(500, 0);
            }

        };
    });
});
```

This is at the bottom of my `index.html.erb` for my `PagesController`. But it also seems to be getting called in `new.html.erb` for my `ContactController`.

Comment: Please show us your code. We can't help you if we can't see what you are doing.

Comment: I edited the question, there was an html `<script> </script>` tag hidden in there . Welcome to stackoverflow . Please use markdown syntax correctly 

Comment: Thank you Gabe and Summer. I have added the code for you guys to see.

Comment: I suggest you give a look at this [Stackoverflow question: How to do per page javascript with the rails asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976430/how-to-do-per-page-javascript-with-the-rails-asset-pipeline)

Comment: GabLeRoux you are my savior. TYSM

Comment: I recorded a screencast on page specific javascript a while back that may be of some assistance as well. Might give you a different approach. https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/page-specific-javascript-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak as to why exactly that's happening within a script tag, but I do know that it is a best practice to use as few  tags as you possible can in a Rails application. What I would do to resolve this issue is to put that in the pages.js file and use this -

```
var new_page_regex = new RegExp(/pages\/new/);

if(new_page_regex.test(window.location.pathname) {
  /* your code here*/
}
```

Comment: If this helped you please consider accepting the answer