# rails asset pipeline - Garber-Irish, Administration & keeping it DRY

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, dry

I'm using the so called [garber-irish technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6892079/435817) for splitting up my javascript files.

My question is, I have a Model (Item say) and have an init function which is in app/assets/javascripts/item/item.js

e.g.

```
MYAPP.items = {
  init: function() {
    alert("do something");
  }
};
```

Now.. lets say I have an administration side to this app, and I don't really want to include the admin javascript in the main bulk.  So.. I have a different system_adminstration.js which requires the *regular* javascripts/item/item.js above, but *also* requires a javascripts/admin/item/item.js which would look something like:

```
MYAPP.items = {
  init: function() {
    alert("also do this");
  }
};
```

I want to load *both* the common javascripts above, and the administation specific ones - effectively merging the two init functions and keeping things nicely dry.

Questions:

1. Is this a sensible approach?
2. It it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keen for comments - but what I have done (for the moment) is change the init function to :

```
UTIL.exec( "common" );
UTIL.exec( controller );
UTIL.exec( "admin_"+controller );
UTIL.exec( controller, action );
UTIL.exec( "admin_"+controller, action );
```

(so, I'm adding in an "admin_") and then for the *admin* javascript files I've simply added in an admin prefix:

```
MYAPP.admin_items = {
  init: function() {
```

....

Slightly nasty but I think it'll do me until someone has a nicer suggestion!