# How can I require a javascript file for a particular resource in a ruby on rails site?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Rails 3.1, where do you put your “page specific” javascript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167805/using-rails-3-1-where-do-you-put-your-page-specific-javascript-code)

I have a controller called course store and I wish to include an external js file from a third party only on that page. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that, particularly due to the 3rd party bit...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work...

```
<%= javascript_include_tag( "http://www.example.com/xmlhr" ) if params[:controller] == 'course_store'  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `content_for`,

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'admin' %>  
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      ...
      ...
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

**More** : http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for