# Update rails app page using AJAX when new data committed to DB

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app with a table at /index. This table is filled with records from the DB. There is another third party service that does a 'post' to this app and creates a new DB record. I want to display this record using AJAX on the /index page without the need to refresh the page.

The new records from the third party service come at a rate of 2 per minute. So I thought of implementing this using a timer loop (of 30 secs) in my javascript which will issue a get at /get_latest_leads and defined a controller action get_latest which gets the records entered/updated in the last 30 secs. Then using the ids (to check duplicate entries in case there are any). On the client side I will pre-pend these new records to the table using javascript.

**controller**

```
# GET /leads
  # GET /leads.json
  def index
    @leads = Lead.find(:all, :conditions => {:is_valid => true}, :order => "id DESC").paginate(:per_page => 30, :page => params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @leads }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def get_latest
    logger.info "in get_latest"
    @leads = Lead.where('updated_at > ?', Time.now - 30.seconds)
    @leads.each { |lead|
      logger.info "#{lead.name}"
    }
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @leads }
    end
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  get 'get_latest_leads', :to => 'leads#get_latest', as: :get_latest_leads
```

**index.js.erb**

```
alert("here1");
setInterval(
  function(){
    new Ajax.Request('get_latest_leads' + '.json', {
      alert("here2");
      method: 'get',
      onSuccess: function(transport){
        var leads = transport.response.responseJSON;
        // insert the last checked time into <div id='time'></div>
        // $('time').innerHTML = records.time;
        // loop over response JSON and do what you want with the data
        leads.each(function(lead){
          $$('table#leads').insert({
            top: '<tr><td>'+lead.attribute+'</td></tr>';
          });
        });
      }
    });
  },
  30000
);
```

The problem is that my js is not being called at all and there is no error on browser/server side. When I do a manual request from my browser at /get_latest_leads.json, it gets me the latest leads as a JSON. But my js is not calling it. Can you please tell me what is going wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I followed instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167805/using-rails-3-1-where-do-you-put-your-page-specific-javascript-code) and moved my js in the app tree accordingly to assets/javascripts/leads/index.js

This made the call successful and now I do get the alerts at every 30 seconds, meaning the function is working. However, now I am getting an "uncaught reference error ajax is not defined".

Comment: I tried to fiddle with _index.js.erb_ which threw syntax errors. Here's what I suggest: remove `alert("here2");` and remove the semi-colon at the end of `top: '<tr><td>'+lead.attribute+'</td></tr>';`.

Comment: @Sunxperous: thanks fro answering, please look at the UPDATE I just added.

Comment: Did you require Prototype in _javascripts/application.js_?

Comment: @Sunxperous: Ummm.. No... I am using jquery-rails. I was under the impression I don't need Prototype then. Am I missing something here? Sorry, I am pretty new to web dev.

Comment: Prototype uses Ajax.Request, while jQuery uses [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: @Sunxperous: got that, just read the documentation. As it is obvious, I had taken the snippet from some place. Note to self: understand what you use. 
Thanks a lot. I'll try the jquery syntax and come back. :)