# Basic questions about javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Please take a peek at the following code, which is in `_form.html.erb`:

```
<script>
    function typeCatch(){
      $.post("<%= update_readers_link_essay_path(@essay) %>");
      $(this).off("keypress", typeCatch);//remove handler
     }

  $(function(){
    ("form#new_revision").on("keypress", typeCatch);
  });
</script>
```

When the user starts typing in a form, the ajax request should be fired and update the readers list. However, the post request is not fired when I start typing in the form and I am trying to debug this problem.

Since I am not that familiar with javacsript yet, I would appreciate if you helped me clarify a few things.

a. For the second part, can I just do

`$("form#new_revision").on("keypress", typeCatch);`

without wrapping it with `$(function() {}` ?

b. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong? Since ajax call isn't fired, I must have made a mistake in the second part?

**Additional Question**

**my_personal_chat.js** (in app/assets/javascripts pipeline)

```
$(function() {
  var pusher = new Pusher('app_key');
  var channel = pusher.subscribe('presence-my-chat');

  channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
    $('#online_users').empty();
    members.each(function(member){
        addMember(member);
    });
... other functions ...
});
```

This is how I implemented my chat feature, using Pusher. Since the channel is private, everytime I call `var channel`, an ajax call to `POST /pusher/auth` is invoked.

I found that every time I navigate to a different page, even when it's not where the chat feature is, `POST /pusher/auth` is called. Basically, every time `my_personal_chat.js` is loaded, the ajax call will be unnecessarily invoked.

Question: How do I prevent this from happening? my_personal_chat.js should only be loaded when I go to `myapp.com/chat`. Should I just pull out everything from the javascript file and put it inside `chat.html.erb`? Is that the conventional way of doing it?

**to answer my own question:** I moved the code from `my_personal_chat.js` to `chat.js.coffee` and deleted `my_personal_chat.js`. Now the javascript only gets loaded when users go to the chat page.

Comment: You're missing the $ from `("form#new_revision").on("keypress", typeCatch)`

Comment: It's you again @FrederickCheung! Thanks so much. Yes, I added it and the problem still persists. Also, don't I need the semicolon at the end?

Comment: Semilcolons are optional in JS.

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript.](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)

Comment: Yes I really should. Still fixing this problem and I will mark as an answer as soon as I get this fixed.

Comment: Well, interpreters insert semicolons automatically, don't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a. There are alternatives, but wrapping the code in `$(function() {})` is one of the best ways to ensure that the code isn't executed until all the elements are loaded into the DOM. It's a jQuery feature.

b. `("form#new_revision").on("keypress", typeCatch);` should be `$("form#new_revision").on("keypress", typeCatch);`. You're missing the `$` at the beginning.

Comment: i loaded jquery library and fix some javascript error and it works.
http://jsfiddle.net/xEu8w/

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. The problem was some other javascript file was not properly imported, and that was giving this code an error.
One additional question though. Suppose I have an external javascript file `foo.js` and I want this to be loaded only when I get to a certain page, `/foo`. I placed `foo.js` inside `app/assets/javascripts` directory, and it gets loaded every time I navigate to another page.

Comment: If it's being loaded even though you don't mention it in a `<script>` tag, that's not a standard Javascript feature. If it's RoR, I don't know anything about that.

Comment: That's due to the asset pipeline in Rails. If you look in /app/assets/javascripts/application.js, you will see a `require_tree` directive - this will load every javascript file in the javascripts folder automatically for you. For more reading on the asset pipeline: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: @sevenseacat Thanks. I was aware of the asset pipeline and I wanted to know how to deal with "controller-specific" javascript files. I could find the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167805/using-rails-3-1-where-do-you-put-your-page-specific-javascript-code, but it's only useful after I get rid of `require_tree`. That would cause manual configuration of javascript imports so I just reverted back to doing `<script>whatever</script>` in my view file.

Comment: Removing the `require_tree` is what most people do. However, including JS on one page isn't very common - it kinda defeats what the pipeline is about, that is, minifying and smooshing all your JS together into a single file for easy serving/caching/etc. Doing inline scripting like that is most definitely not recommended.