# using javascript_include_tag on heroku.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am using a javascript plugin which requires the dom to be loaded before use. 
So I am loading all javascript files on applications.js except from the one file 
that I load dynamically with the javascript_include_tag, 
this works fine on localhost but when I push to heroku it doesn't find the file. 
Should I precompile the assets in order for this to work ?

Comment: When pushing to heroku, one of the automatic steps that gets run is assets:precompile. To reproduce the issue locally, run your app in production mode: `rake assets:precompile` (and) `RAILS_ENV=production rails server`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asset pipeline: use javascript files for only one controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899542/asset-pipeline-use-javascript-files-for-only-one-controller)

Comment: I think you need to add that file to `config.assets.precompile`