# Rails Asset pipeline manage issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm making a page that needs real-time data.

So, it needs a repeatable ajax communication after page loads.

like this,

```
jQuery ->
  setInterval -> 
    $.ajax
      url: "some url"
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
       #handle the data here
```

the problem occurs here,

i only need this code in `one page`

but because of this in `application.js`

```
require_tree .
```

it loads the whole coffeescript(javascript) code in every pages.

How do i include this coffeescript file in only one page?

Do i have to manually include the javascript in `.erb` file like this?

```
<%=javascript_include_tag 'what_i_want'%>
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: Either you can include the script in your .erb file itself or create a separate js file and call that js file using your above rails tag.

Comment: I cant' understand the second one. create a separate js file and call that js file using your above rails tag.

Comment: create a new js file something like real_time.js and add your ajax script in that file and then call js file using <%= javascript_include_tag 'real_time' %>

Comment: If you will add it too your erb file directly you need to add your js file in config/initializers/assets.rb

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['what_i_want.js'']

Comment: Find a good solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167805/using-rails-3-1-where-do-you-put-your-page-specific-javascript-code

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your erb file.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'what_i_want' %>
```

If you will add it too your erb file directly you need to add your js file in **config/initializers/assets.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['what_i_want.js']
```