# Load page specific JS and CSS file in rails view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rendering

Hi I'm making a Widget which display a page from rails application in Iframe.
Since the remote page was developed in rails, On rendering single page on Iframe, It loads all the JS and CSS file so page on iFrame takes too much time to load.

I was trying to use `layout: false` while rendering the page but it doesn't load any of its JS and CSS file.

Is there any way to include specific JS and CSS file in rails view?

Comment: Create a separate layout for the widget page, avoid mixing up the CSS and JS files of the widget with the CSS and JS files of your Rails app

Comment: Hi sounds great!!! What about the Vendor'file?

Comment: What vendor file are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Rails 3.1, where do you put your "page specific" javascript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167805/using-rails-3-1-where-do-you-put-your-page-specific-javascript-code)

Comment: I've Bootstrap, jQuery Validation and some other files

Comment: Create a new layout and put the required assets there

Comment: Okey
thank you very much. You made my day

Answer (score 2):

On a page you can write to include stylesheet as

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'filename' %>
## If your file reside under any folder then you have to write 'foldername/filename'
```

and you can include javascript file as:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'filename' %>
```