# Understanding Rails with webpacker and incidence on JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, zxing

A rails 6 application calls from a legacy application being migrated:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'zxing.js' %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    let selectedDeviceId;
    const codeReader = new ZXing.BrowserMultiFormatReader()
    console.log('ZXing code reader initialized')
    codeReader.listVideoInputDevices()
      .then((videoInputDevices) => {
        const sourceSelect = document.getElementById('sourceSelect')
        selectedDeviceId = videoInputDevices[0].deviceId
        if (videoInputDevices.length >= 1) {
          videoInputDevices.forEach((element) => {
            const sourceOption = document.createElement('option')
            sourceOption.text = element.label
            sourceOption.value = element.deviceId
            sourceSelect.appendChild(sourceOption)
          })

          sourceSelect.onchange = () => {
            selectedDeviceId = sourceSelect.value;
          };

          const sourceSelectPanel = document.getElementById('sourceSelectPanel')
          sourceSelectPanel.style.display = 'block'
        }

        document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
          codeReader.decodeFromVideoDevice(selectedDeviceId, 'video', (result, err) => {
            if (result) {
              console.log(result)
              document.getElementById('result').textContent = result.text
let formData = new FormData();
let CodeParams = {
code_data: result.text,
shopkeeper_id:  <%= current_user.id %>
};
formData.append("code_json_data", JSON.stringify(CodeParams));
$.ajax({
url: "new_moviment",
type: "post",
data: formData,
   processData: false,
  contentType: false,
 });
            }
            if (err && !(err instanceof ZXing.NotFoundException)) {
              console.error(err)
              document.getElementById('result').textContent = err
            }
          })
          console.log(`Started continous decode from camera with id ${selectedDeviceId}`)
        })

        document.getElementById('resetButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
          codeReader.reset()
          document.getElementById('result').textContent = '';
          console.log('Reset.')
        })

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
      })
  })
```

The javascript is loading, but the script for the page is not `Uncaught ReferenceError: ZXing is not defined`

THe [ZXing documentation](https://github.com/zxing-js/library) does provide different code bases according to whether one is `Use on browser with ES6 modules` or `AMD`, `UMD`, or `CommonJS`.

I am under the impression that with the move to webpacker, Rails is pre-processing under ES6.  But that impression is confused by the fact that there is browser-based code and module-based code.

How should this script be edited (and are there - for JS-knotheads - online tools to allow to identify and change  syntax for ES6 ?)

**Update**

After a `yarn add @zxing/library` packs/application.js edited to

```
require("@zxing/library")
import("../src/qr_scan")
```

src/qr_scan.js is now as follows:

```
import { BrowserMultiFormatReader, NotFoundException } from '@zxing/library';

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  let selectedDeviceId;
  const codeReader = new BrowserMultiFormatReader() // note the updated module reference
    console.log('ZXing code reader initialized')
    codeReader.listVideoInputDevices()
      .then((videoInputDevices) => {
        const sourceSelect = document.getElementById('sourceSelect')
        selectedDeviceId = videoInputDevices[0].deviceId
        if (videoInputDevices.length >= 1) {
          videoInputDevices.forEach((element) => {
            const sourceOption = document.createElement('option')
            sourceOption.text = element.label
            sourceOption.value = element.deviceId
            sourceSelect.appendChild(sourceOption)
          })

          sourceSelect.onchange = () => {
            selectedDeviceId = sourceSelect.value;
          };

          const sourceSelectPanel = document.getElementById('sourceSelectPanel')
          sourceSelectPanel.style.display = 'block'
        }

        document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
          codeReader.decodeFromVideoDevice(selectedDeviceId, 'video', (result, err) => {
            if (result) {
              console.log(result)
              document.getElementById('result').textContent = result.text

              let formData = new FormData();
              let CodeParams = {
              code_data: result.text
              };
              formData.append("code_json_data", JSON.stringify(CodeParams));
              $.ajax({
              url: 'new_user',
              type: "post",
              data: formData,
                 processData: false,
                contentType: false,
               });
            }
           if (err && !(err instanceof ZXing.NotFoundException)) {
              console.error(err)
              document.getElementById('result').textContent = err
            }
          })
          console.log(`Started continous decode from camera with id ${selectedDeviceId}`)
        })

        document.getElementById('resetButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
          codeReader.reset()
          document.getElementById('result').textContent = '';
          console.log('Reset.')
        })

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
      })
  })
```

and the view page has no more javascript references.  Loading the page however leads to the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _zxing_library__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.BrowserMultiFormatReader is not a constructor
```

pointing to `codeReader` line.  The page was processed with webpacker attempting to compile.

Although `js/zxing-3544fb3b633f87715d29.js   528 KiB                  zxing  [emitted] [immutable]  zxing` is successfully built (`[./app/javascript/packs/zxing.js] 524 KiB {zxing} [built]`), both the import functions failed:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/src/qr_scan.js 4:23-47
"export 'BrowserMultiFormatReader' was not found in '@zxing/library'
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js

ERROR in ./app/javascript/src/qr_scan.js 47:36-53
"export 'NotFoundException' was not found in '@zxing/library'
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
```

searches on those strings in the zxing compiled file only reveal two instances:

```
e.BrowserMultiFormatReader = s;
e.NotFoundException = l["default"];
```

leading naturally to a console error:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var selectedDeviceId;
  var codeReader = new _zxing_library__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["BrowserMultiFormatReader"](); // note the updated module reference
```

Webpacker finally compiled when reverting to the [library's documentation](https://github.com/zxing-js/library#usage) referenced command

```
const codeReader = new BrowserQRCodeReader() // note the updated module reference
//  const codeReader = new BrowserMultiFormatReader() // note the updated module reference
```

but now, there is a console error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: BrowserQRCodeReader is not defined
```

pointing to `var codeReader = new BrowserQRCodeReader();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript modules in webpack are not exported to the global scope, i.e., when using Webpacker with Rails, you can't reference something like `ZXing` from a `<script>` tag in an ERB template by default.

Instead, you would move all your JavaScript to the `app/javascript` directory and update your ZXing (and other library) references to use module imports.

Rails will treat everything in the "packs" folder as a separate bundle. Start with just an application pack that points to your source code:

```
app/
  javascript/
    packs/
      application.js
    src/
      my_barcode.js
```

```js
// app/javascript/packs/application.js

import '../src/my_barcode'
```

```js
// app/javascript/src/my_barcode.js

// Based off the module imports described in the ZXing README
import { BrowserMultiFormatReader, NotFoundException } from '@zxing/library/esm';

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  let selectedDeviceId;
  const codeReader = new BrowserMultiFormatReader() // note the updated module reference
  // and so on ...
```

And in your application layout:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

Comment: You mention `note the updated module reference` I fail to see the module being invoked per se.  Is the `import '../src/my_barcode'` another syntax for saying 'module' ?  Also, that would place the script on all pages (& it is a bit heavy)  The alternative is to `packs/my_barcode.js` and call `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'my_barcode' %>`, yes?

Comment: Also, you added `NotFoundException` to the import call.  That is not distinctly mentioned in the library documentation.  What was the reasoning behind this insertion?

Comment: > Is the import '../src/my_barcode' another syntax for saying 'module' ?
Almost. In ES6, whatever is exported from a single file is considered a module.

Comment: > that would place the script on all pages?

Correct

Comment: > The alternative is to packs/my_barcode.js and call <%= javascript_pack_tag 'my_barcode' %>, yes?

Correct, but, be careful with doing this in webpack. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59493803/using-rails-6-where-do-you-put-your-page-specific-javascript-code and my blog post https://rossta.net/blog/rails-apps-overpacking-with-webpacker.html

Comment: > you added NotFoundException to the import call?

Because you're referencing `ZXing.NotFoundException` in your original source. That exception is exported from the zxing libary: https://github.com/zxing-js/library/blob/e7d06784f0b561040a18253556f9c4a50bd8cbd3/src/index.ts#L11

Comment: >  my blog post.     Good!  My mental model needs strengthening!

Comment: The question was edited. Some evolution, but not conclusive.

Comment: Answer updated: trying changing your import to `ìmport '@zxing/library/esm'` which will point to the ES exports from this particular library.

Also, you can remove the `require('@zxing/library')` from `'application.js'`, that's not doing anything for you.

Comment: that error pops up whether or not the import is suffixed.  It seems faster when added.  Novel odditiy:  the process functions as per design in both cases...